# Error :Could not connect to Redis at redis:6379: Name or service not known

Tags: redis, docker

I am trying to execute the container named **redis** which is running right now.But the error `Could not connect to Redis at redis:6379: Name or service not known`. Any one please hell me to figure out the issue and fix it.

Comment: You're going to need to give us a lot more details. How did you run the container and how did you try to connect to it?

Comment: it is very weird, that i encounter this very same problem. I keep typing same command and open different shells...Until, after a while... `redis-cli` is finally able to connect. I also noticed, that during when it cannot connect, I have to type `exit` command twice just to close the shell. I am using `redis-cli 4.0.6` and my redis server running in docker is `4.0.2`. Also, I am in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 7):

Naming the container doesn't alter your hosts file or DNS, and depending on how you ran the container it may not be accessible via the standard port as Docker does port translation.

Run `docker inspect redis` and examine the ports output, it will tell you what port it is accessible on as well as the IP. Note, however, that this will only be connectable over that IP from that host. To access it from off of the host you will need to use the port from the above command and the host's IP address. That assumes your local firewall rules allow it, which are beyond the scope of this site.

Answer (score 7):

This is because both the containers are not in same network, Add a network property inside service name and make sure its same for both

```
    redis:
      networks:
        - redis-net
```

Comment: God bless you. I have been searching fo hours what was the reason and adding the network solved the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try below command

```
src/redis-cli -h localhost -p 6379
```

Comment: thanks.. yes separating the port is working `-p 6379`