# Flask app using Redis in Docker container failing on Azure Deployment (works locally): Error -2 connecting to redis:6379. Name or service not known

Tags: azure, docker, flask, redis, docker-compose

I am experiencing an issue when deploying a Flask application on Azure. The application is a simple Flask app that uses Celery as a task queue with Redis as a message broker. The app works fine on my local machine (Windows 10) when I call `docker-compose up --build`. I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong when deploying the application to Azure.

The app seems to deploy okay, except when I try to execute an asynchronous task - it hangs and gives an unexpected error response in the browser.

Here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '2'

services:
  redis:
    image: 'redis:3.0-alpine'
    command: redis-server
    volumes:
      - 'redis:/var/lib/redis/data'
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'

  website:
      - celery
    build: .
    command: >
      gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000
        --access-logfile -
        --reload
        "flask_app.app:create_app()"
    environment:
      PYTHONUNBUFFERED: 'true'
    volumes:
      - '.:/flask_app'
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'

  celery:
    restart: always
    build: .
    command: celery worker -l info -A flask_app.tasks
    env_file:
      - '.env'
    volumes:
      - '.:/flask_app'

volumes:
  redis:
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7.5-slim-buster

ENV INSTALL_PATH /flask_app
RUN mkdir -p $INSTALL_PATH

WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5000 6379
CMD gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 --access-logfile - "flask_app.app:create_app()"
```

Here are is a snippet of the error logs:

```
ERROR] Error handling request /longtask
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 559, in connect
  sock = self._connect()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 585, in _connect
  socket.SOCK_STREAM):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 748, in getaddrinfo
  for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 127, in reconnect_on_error
  yield
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 177, in _consume_from
  self._pubsub.subscribe(key)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 3580, in subscribe
  ret_val = self.execute_command('SUBSCRIBE', *iterkeys(new_channels))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 3468, in execute_command
  self.shard_hint
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 1192, in get_connection
  connection.connect()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 563, in connect
  raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error -2 connecting to redis:6379. Name or service not known.
```

What I have tried:

- Including a `.gitattributes` file in my repository to ensure that the shell script uses LF for end of lines.
- Including a network in the docker-compose file as advised in this post: [Error :Could not connect to Redis at redis:6379: Name or service not known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33142139/error-could-not-connect-to-redis-at-redis6379-name-or-service-not-known)
- Adding in 'depends_on: -celery -redis' into the docker-compose file as advised elsewhere on StackOverflow.
  [How to deploy multiple MEAN app containers to Azure using Docker-Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54174175/how-to-deploy-multiple-mean-app-containers-to-azure-using-docker-compose)

It looks as though the redis service can't be discovered by the application or is not starting up properly on Azure (using Docker Compose Preview). I am new to web development, Azure and Stack Overflow. I am not too sure how to troubleshoot this issue on Azure and would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you try to start Redis separately, wait until it properly starts and then start the other website?